# What constitutes spam in a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, spam

Recently I came across a user on a site who:

- Was affiliated with a product/service (according to their profile).
- Was active on the site (i.e. clearly not a spam bot).
- Edited mention of their product/service into other tag wikis (all of these were rolled back by me or others, these were clearly inappropriate).
- Also created a *new* tag wiki entry specifically dedicated to their product/service, with links to the site, that sort of read like an advertisement. *However*, there were actually a fair number of questions with this tag that already existed on said site.

So the "edit" case clearly was spam to me, or at the very least, an unnecessary addition of an unremarkable specific product. But the "new tag wiki" case, the dedicated tag, while it *feels* like spam, it isn't actually that much different than any other legitimate tag wiki entry (description of something and a link to it if it's a product/service). The only potentially "questionable" part was the author's affiliation.

So my question is: What constitutes spam in a tag wiki? What is allowed, what isn't allowed, what rules must be followed, and when is a rollback/deletion justified?

Comment: As a base requirement, you have to attribute content you copy from anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [we recently settled a similar issue on Law](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/), I think a modification of my answer there would be fair.

> If a link is additional to or directly supports a good tag description, it's a good link. Leave it there.
>
> If the link forms the majority of the description, or does not add to/support a good description, it's a bad link. Edit to remove unhelpful or irrelevant content.
>
> The "bad link" category becomes spam when it is also self-promoting. Flag as spam.

Comment: This seems like an extremely reasonable rule set. I'll let the community give a little more feedback, but I really like this criteria in general, and it applies equally well to tag wikis as it does to answers. A form of it is also applicable to products that are named but not directly linked.